# when reportlab draw a long string, how to auto wrap?

Tags: reportlab

```
long_line = '''
xhtml2pdf is a html2pdf converter using the ReportLab Toolkit, the HTML5lib and pyPdf. It supports HTML 5 and CSS 2.1 (and some of CSS 3). It is completely written in pure Python so it is platform independent.
'''
can.drawString(0, 700, long_line)
```

The string is too long, so not all of it can show in the pdf page, how to auto-wrap it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want auto wrapping you are probably best off using Platypus or RML with ReportLab. If you draw directly on the canvas you will have to manage string wrapping yourself.